# Assinatura digital de software

Tags: windows, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital

Uso o antivirus *Kaspersky* e para que ele permitisse meu software, escrito em Delphi, rodar eu precisei marcar nele como software confiável.

O motivo que o *Kaspersky* deu foi que o software não é confiável por não ser assinado digitalmente.

Observando o link que o @epx [passou](http://windowsitpro.com/security/q-whats-easiest-way-digitally-sign-internally-developed-applications-executable), pude verificar que é necessário o uso de certificados para fazer a assinatura digital:

> Before you can get started, you'll need a code-signing certificate and
>   associated private key.

Logo em seguida diz que eu posso gerar uma chave em minha infraestrutura:

> You can generate your proper code-signing certificate using your
>   internal Windows public key infrastructure (PKI) or you can buy one
>   from a commercial Certification Authority (CA) such as Verisign.

Então gostaria de saber:

```
1- O que é assinatura digital de software?     
2- Preciso realmente dela para fornecer software e não ter o mesmo tipo de problema com o Kaspersky e outros antivirus?  
3- Como assino meu software digitalmente? 
4- Como gerar esse certificado em minha infraestrutura? 
5- Ela seria aceita pelo *Kaspersky*, por exemplo?
```

Comment: Parece que a forma mais fácil de assinar um programa interno é utilizar um programa chamado signtool que vem no SDK do .NET: http://windowsitpro.com/security/q-whats-easiest-way-digitally-sign-internally-developed-applications-executable

Comment: A parte da pergunta "preciso realmente dela?" é difícil responder sem saber o que você quer... Precisaria saber o que você deseja alcançar.

Comment: Eu realmente deixei a pergunta de uma forma muita ampla e está com um texto nada legal, vou ajustar. Agora, remover a tag delphi não vai deixar a questão muito fora do contexto do SOpt? A propósito, inclui a tag [delphi] porque escrevi o sistema em [delphi] e também essa é uma "linguagem" muito visada por programas antivirus, então pensei que com essa tag, alguém acostumado a lidar com esse tipo de problema poderia dar uma ajuda.

Comment: Acredito que tudo tenha ficado mais compreensível agora. Vou ler sua resposta e os links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você criou, na verdade, várias perguntas que talvez fossem melhor exploradas se estivessem separadas. Mas vou tentar responder mesmo assim.

A grosso modo, [assinatura digital](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assinatura_digital) seria como o reconhecimento de firma e a autenticação de documentos no cartório, só que para arquivos digitais. Ela confirma quem emitiu arquivo e que esse arquivo não foi alterado depois que saiu das mãos do criador.
A assinatura de código ou executáveis para o Windows é chamado pela Microsoft **Authenticode**.

Alguns artigos da Microsoft sobre o assunto:
[Introdução a assinatura de códigos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380259%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#introduction_to_code_signing)
[Authenticode no MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[Explicação sobre Authenticode no blog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750035.aspx)
[Criando, visualizando e gerenciando certificados](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379872%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Para assinar digitalmente você precisa de um certificado.
Você pode gerar um certificado para você mesmo [utilizando openSSL](http://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/12/30/howto-make-your-own-cert-with-openssl/) ou o [MakeCert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Mas como você não é reconhecido por outras empresas como alguém que emite certificados de confiança, nem todos vão dar total confiança ao seu software. Cabe a você verificar se a assinatura gerada por você vai resolver o seu problema ou não.

Abaixo uma lista com alguns vendedores de certificados que em geral são considerados confiáveis:

http://www.verisign.com
http://www.thawte.com
http://www.globalsign.net
http://www.geotrust.com

Uma alternativa mais barata é obter o certificado pela empresa COMODO via o site Tucows: https://author.tucows.com/article.php?sid=&account_id=&id=2536

Comment: Quando você diz que posso gerar meu certificado e ver se resolverá o meu problema, eu já logo penso que essa questão de gerar certificados eu mesmo seria mais viável para aplicações internas. Já para aplicações que serão distribuidas ao público e irão rodar fora de meu ambiente, mesmo que resolvesse o problema no momento, futuramente eu provavelmente seria pressionado a ter um certificado de uma entitidade certificadora reconhecida. Logo, se eu tivesse mesmo que distribuir os softwares assinados seria bom já obter um e uma entidade certificadora.

Comment: @Tiago é mais ou menos por aí. O problema é que os certificados costumam ser caros e dependendo da certificadora, **muito** caros.

Comment: Um fragmento de sua resposta, `e que esse arquivo não foi alterado depois que saiu das mãos do criador`. Isso é válido para o software que foi assinado também? Porque isso eu creio que ajudaria muito na luta contra vírus infectantes, não é mesmo?

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: desculpe pois não entendi essa sua última afirmação. Realmente a verificação de integridade serve para software também?

Comment: @Tiago, agora eu que fiquei confuso. O objetivo da assinatura digital **é** a verificação de integridade. Ela serve tanto para arquivos como para executáveis. Adicionei na resposta outro artigo da Microsoft que dá uma introdução sobre o assunto.

Comment: desculpe, eu só quis te sugar um pouco mais de informação :) E era isso mesmo que quis saber nessa pergunta feita aqui pelos comentários. E obrigado!

Comment: @Tiago de nada. Acha que poderia mudar algo na resposta pra deixá-la mais clara?

Comment: Não, está ótimo! Links ótimos! Muito esclarecedor.. grato!